# Conditional converting, aggregate/ group-by of data frame based on information from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions

Say my data frame looks as follows,

```
df.head()
 col1   col2    col3    start   end gs
chr1    HAS GEN 11869   14409   DDX
chr1    HAS TRANS   11869   14409   Tp1
chr1    HAS EX  11869   12227   Tp2
chr1    HAS EX  12613   12721   Tp3
chr1    HAS EX  13221   14409   Tp4
```

And I want to convert the above data frame or group by the above data frame as,

```
df_converted.head()
gs  chr      strt   end           ex_start           ex_end 
DDX chr1    11869   14409   11869, 12613,13221  12227,12721,14409
```

The converted data frame should have two additional columns `ex_start` and `ex_end`, based on the columns `col3`, `start`, and `end` information. So, if `col3` is equal to `EX`, then generate the `ex_start` and `ex_end` columns. However, keep the first value of column `gs`.

I tried making lists and join them together, however, I do not get through this, here is what I have tried.

```
df.query('col3 == "EX"').groupby('gs').agg({'start': list})
gs  start
NA  [11869, 12613,13221]
```

However, this above one liner is generating dataframe with a column of list 
using `NA` in `gs`. Not the first value.

The logics:

1. if `col3` is equal to `EX`, then generate the `ex_start`
   and use values from `start` as a comma-separated list.

   2. So as, if `col3` is equal to `EX`, then generate second the `ex_end`
      and use values from `end` as a comma-separated list.
   3. Always take the first value of `gs` column

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the grouping logic? Same value for `col1` and `col2`? A new *group* is started on each row with a non NaN gs? Or still another logic?

Comment: Logic 1. if `col3` is `EX` and logic 2. the column `gs` has ` ID` in my current example it is `DDX` and rest is `NA` so we need to group-by on column `gs`. IF the conditions meet,  Then always use the value in column `start ` in new column `ex_start ` as comma separated list and so for column `end` in `ex_end` column

Comment: I am not sure what work best for my case

Comment: what if `col3` is not `EX`? How `ex_start` and `ex_end` should be buildt in this case?

Comment: If col3 is not `EX` it will not affect the `ex_start` column as it is a list of comma seperated values. the list should always be written with next value.

Comment: I got that, but I mean: the values in the rows where `col3` is not `EX` are not included in the final result?

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: I appologize for confusiong the `NA`s in initial question were unwanted strings . Now, I have added the right strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the following code will:

- start a new *group* when the `gs` column has a value
- concatenate the values of the `start` and `end` columns for rows following each *group leader* having `'EX'` in the `col3` column to build the new columns

Code:

```
df1 = df.loc[~(df['gs'].isna()), ['gs', 'col2', 'start', 'end']].rename_axis({'col2': 'chr'}, axis=1)
df.loc[~(df['gs'].isna()), 'ix'] = df.loc[~(df['gs'].isna())].index
df['ix'].ffill(inplace=True)
df2 = df.loc[df['col3']=='EX', ['ix', 'start', 'end']].groupby(['ix']).agg(
        lambda x: ','.join([str(y) for y in x]))
df2.columns= ['ex_start', 'ex_end']
result = df1.join(df2)
```

The result dataframe is as expected:

```
    gs  chr  start    end           ex_start             ex_end
0  DDX  HAS  11869  14409  11869,12613,13221  12227,12721,14409
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Sorry, That I was unclear in the question. The `NAs` that in my primary question was unwanted strings. I have now replaced them with real strings. They were not `NA`s. Sorry about that. And hence the seound line is not correctly generating the `ix` column.